# Restore value in NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, numericupdown

I have a NumericUpDown. When the user changes its value, I show a MessageBox to confirm. If the user selected Yes, all is well. If the user selected No, I want to restore the original value.

I have run into two problems:

Q1. How to get the original value.
I store it in a private member variable, which is updated when user selects Yes. But I would like to know if there is a better way.

Q2. Changing the value to the original value again triggers my event handler.
I have put a if condition to handle that.

Here is my current code:

```
if (mNumericUpDownValue != mReactantNumericUpDown.Value)
{
    bool change = !mIsModified;
    if (mIsModified && ReportChangeWarning())
    {
        change = true;
    }
    if (change)
    {
        mReactantGroup = (int)mReactantNumericUpDown.Value;
        ClearUserValues();
        UpdateControls();
    }
    else
    {
        mReactantNumericUpDown.Value = mNumericUpDownValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Q1 is fine. Store the original value when binding your controls or whenever the user commits to a value changed. Regarding Q2, the simplest might be when resetting to the old value, first deregister your event `ValueChanged` listener, change the value, reassign the event listener. I don't know off the top of my head if `NumericUpDown` has a specialized event that only fires when the value changes due to user input.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know we can deregister an event. I was googling for that before I came here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are binding to your value you could simply prevent changing the number at all until the user confirms.  You would write the property like this:

```
    private int _testNumber;

    public int TestNumber
    {
        get { return _testNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (_testNumber != value)
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Change value?", "Change Value?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

                if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                {
                    _testNumber = value;                        
                }

                RaisePropertyChanged("TestNumber");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this logic can be simplified
(but I like the answer from TrueEddie -  this was too much for a comment)

```
if (isModified & !Report)
{
   mReactantNumericUpDown.Value = mNumericUpDownValue;   
}
else
{
   mReactantGroup = (int)mReactantNumericUpDown.Value;
   ClearUserValues();
   UpdateControls();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you implement [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) on your models to accomplish this behavior. It's really quite straight forward and IMHO the correct way of doing what you want.

Comment: I will try to implement this and will let you guys know. I didn't know something like that existed. Thanks.